# ¿Cómo puedo tener variables equivalentes a las public static final de Java en NodeJs?

Tags: java, nodejs

Estoy iniciando en NodeJs después de tener un manejo en java y la cuestión es que yo manejo una clase en Java llamada **Parameters** para tener variables estáticas, la cuestión es que quiero saber como hacer algo similar en Node, estaba mirando lo de las variables `global` pero hasta donde he leído no es buena opción, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradezco.

**Ejemplo JAVA**

```
public static final String NOMBRE = "Juanito";
```

Comment: El sistema de herencia de Javascript no tiene nada que ver con el sistema de herencia de Java. Las Clases de JavaScript sólo son azúcar sintáctico de funciones. Dicho esto, la estructura que pretendes implementar no está definida en Javascript. Te sugiero que estudies el sistema de herencia de JavaScript, que se basa en prototipos. Otra sugerencia es que uses Typescript que te permitirá desarrollar de una forma más cercana a lo que haces en Java, pero nunca exactamente igual. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

através de la palabra clave  [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

```
node -e "const a = 3; a = 5; console.log(a);" // 3
```

Comment: Al momento de utilizarlo en otros archivos, debería de exportarlo e importarlos en otro archivo? o debería manejar una clase e importar dicha clase?

Comment: Esto no es lo que pregunta el OP. Su pregunta se relaciona con atributos de clase y herencia. Tu respuesta, establece que una variable primitiva declarada con `const` no puede ser redeclarada ni redefinida, pero cuando se usa con valores no primitivos (objetos, funciones, Arrays, clases), las propiedades de estos pueden ser sobreescritas a pesar del uso de `const`. Saludos